# Problem with heteroscedastic residuals using lme with varIdent

Tags: r

I´m having problems when I try to fix heteroscedasticity in mixed models with lme.

My experimental design consists of 12 independent enclosures (Encl) with populations of lizards (Subject_ID). We applied 2 crossed treatments (Lag: 3 levels and Var: 2 levels). And we repeated the experiment two years (Year), so individuals that survived the first year, were measured again the next year. We analyse the snout vent length (SVL) in mm. Sex (males and females). This was my model:

```
    ctrl <- lmeControl(maxIter=200, msMaxIter=200, msVervose=TRUE, opt="optim")

    options (contrast=c(factor="contr.sum", ordered="contr.poly")) 

    model.SVL <- lme(SVL~Lag*Var*Sex*Year, random=list(~1|Subject_ID, ~1|Encl), control=ctrl, data=data)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCvFY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTrhj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsJNX.png)

The model showed heteroscedasticity in several triple interactions using bartlett.test, so I corrected it with varIdent. However, heteroscedasticity was not fixed, and now, qqplot indicates leptokurtic distribution.

```
model.SVL2 <- lme(SVL~Lag*Var*Sex*Year, random=list(~1|Subject_ID, ~1|Encl), control=ctrl, weights=varIdent (form=~1|Lag*Var*Sex*Year), data=data)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

What could be the problem?

I think the problem is using varIdent when I include Subject_ID as a random factor. If I remove it, this doesn't happen. Maybe it is because many individuals do not survive two years, and it is a random factor with many levels but few replications

Comment: Since a lizard lives in only one enclosure, I would model this nested random effects as `random=list(~ 1 | Encl / Subject_ID)` or even `~ Encl | Subject_ID` to give one slope per enclosure and one intercept for every lizard.

Comment: Thank you. I already tried, but it gives me the following error message: Error in lme.formula(SVL ~ Lag * Var * Sex * Year, random = list(~Encl |  : 
  fewer observations than random effects in all level 1 groups. And, with ~1|Encl/Subject_ID, Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) : 
  NAs in foreign function call (arg 2)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In ncols * isLast :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In ncols * c(rep(1, Q), 0, 0) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: have you tried any data transformation? square root or log transformation for example?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried the transformations of lambert, and Box Cox...

Comment: You used a full model combining all interaction terms with `*`. If you don't have so much data, you can create a reduced model with less coeffs to fit. Does `SVL~Lag*Var + (1| Encl / Subject_ID)`  work? Or just remove Encl. You do not need it if you use subject as a random factor anyways...

Comment: I can fit a model removing Encl, but I have the same leptokurtic qqplot... And I created a reduced model with less coeffs, but when I fix the model with varIdent, I always see the same normality distribution. I have tested one by one all the coeff of the model individually using Subject_ID as a random factor (without Encl), and they all generate the same qqplot.